# Why do some artists tune their guitars half a step or whole step down?

Tags: guitar, tuning, alternative-tunings

Is there a reason some guitarists tune down half or whole steps, other than preference or style?

It bugs me sometimes when I would like to play along with a song only to find that it's played down half or a whole step.

I have purchased software that enables me to adjust the pitch of songs without affecting the tempo, etc, and my guitar tab software can transpose tabs, but knowing why artists do this in the first place would be helpful.

Comment: They do it to bug you; Some artists are like that you know, they forget where they came from and who's buying their music. And, I agree, it would be considerate of them to say when they are going to tune down a half or whole step, though, out of courtesy to them I think we should let them tune two steps or more unannounced. :-)

Comment: I remember reading that stevie ray vaughan used the thickest strings he could find and then tune a semi tone down so that they become a little more manageable.

Comment: Is pitch shifting the audio and transposing the tab less effort than retuning your guitar or having a second one on-hand that's already tuned down?

Comment: @alfonso well... yeah, it's just a button press in Guitar Pro, but that wasn't the point of the question (which I might also add is now over 10 years old). I wasn't _complaining_ about it, just asking for reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Jasarien, oh my mistake. Your question was in my digest email last week. You were using guitar pro a decade ago and this is the first I hear of it. I'm pretty old I guess... wow!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Lots of reasons; the most prevalent reason is probably so that they can keep the tune within the range of their voice.  Jimi Hendrix was famous for this; tuned a half step down.

Other reasons; to create a different atmosphere in the music; as in the case of Metal where instruments are down-tuned to create the darkest most aggressive sounding riffs possible.

Comment: And Muddy Waters was known for capoing on the second fret and playing and singing songs in F#. Perhaps that suit his voice better.

Comment: This answer assumes the guitarist is using predominantly open chords, but I still doubt that one semitone down will affect the range of any song enough to make it worthwhile.Does a 5 fret bar A chord  sound much different from a 4 fret Ab chord ? (Obviously not in a key situation)

Comment: Well, for metal the low E string is used predominantly, and a half or whole step down makes a difference.

Comment: Tuning down also effects the overall sound of the instrument, even when playing fretted notes.

Comment: I agree with Tim, I think this reasoning is off. If the range was an issue, they'd just play in a different key.

Answer (score 24):

An additional point is that a guitar tuned a half/whole step down will be easier to play with higher action or larger gauge strings due to the less tension on the strings required to maintain the right pitch. I believe I have an interview with Stevie Ray Vaughn around here somewhere where he cites this, as well as many other reasons, as to why he played a half step down.

Comment: It also makes it easier to rattle the strings against the frets == acoustic distortion.

Answer (score 7):

Another reason is to make it easier to bend strings. A great example would be Jerry Cantrell from Alice in Chains. He constantly bends up a semi or whole tone and mostly all his songs are in Eb standard or Drop C# tuning.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the main reason. It seems it played a role for Iommi (Black Sabbath), though, to ease the tension on his faux fingertips.

Answer (score 7):

I have done this in the past with 12-string guitars for the simple reason that it makes the high G string last longer! On a 12, the G string has a double that is an octave higher, making it significantly higher and tenser than any string on a normal 6-string. It's always the first string to snap.

Another reason why records don't always seem to be in the expected key is that varispeed recording was very popular at one time. The Beatles used it a lot; *Rain* was slowed down, while many other songs were speeded up. *Strawberry Fields Forever* was made of two halves, one slowed down, the other speeded up.

Some guitarists tune their guitar up a tone, whether to fit the range of a vocalist or to get a brighter sound from the tension in the strings. Johnny Marr would do that. (Of course this is far less of a problem if you're playing along as you can just use a capo.)

Answer (score 4):

I was under the impression that drop tuning also makes it easier to do some power chords. For example: dropping the tuning on the E string allows single finger power chords.

Comment: The idea being discussed seems to be moving the tuning from **EBGDAE** to **DAFCGD**, while you're taking Drop-D, which moves the tuning to **EBGDAD**. It's a common and useful thing, but not what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that guitarists use alternate tunings to make it easier to play songs in keys other than E, A and D.

One example of a reason for this would be to accompany a singer who insists that a certain song needs to be sung in a lower key than the one the guitarist learned it in.

Another example would be when the guitarist determines that in a particular song, he needs to play low notes that are lower than the low "E" on the guitar when it is in standard tuning.

Answer (score 2):

For a variety of reasons:

- They like the sound of the looser strings and lower pitches (many dark metal acts)
- They like the snappier, jangly sound of tighter, higher pitched strings (e.g. Johnny Marr of The Smiths)
- They want to play certain open-string chords, while keeping the song within their vocal range
- They want to play certain open-string chords, while being in a key that is convenient for their accompanying musicians (for example, you've learned chords in E; I want to play the melody on a diatonic melodeon in D)
- They didn't use any form of reference pitch when tuning

Answer (score 1):

Advantages:

1) better accomadates a particular vocal range     try singing simple man by LS in standard tuning.
LS tuned their guitars down 1/2 step.....another good example....several Neil Young songs....down by the river...only love can break your heart. Even neil on occasion, when his range shifts for whatever reason, tunes his guitar down a half step...     the song the Joker by Steve Miller is tuned down a full step.

2) makes bar chords and lead a bit easier to play because of less string tension

3) can possibly extend life of strings? maybe? I don't know for sure, but it make sense.

4) Can always capo up to standard tuning, whereas going from standard to lower tunings requites physically retuning your guitar

Disadavantages

1) When asked to sit in with other musicians, re-tuning to standard, if that's what they're using, can be a pain in the ass. Unfortunately, the term "standard" tuning, besides the fact that it is the guitar tuning used most frequently, can play havoc with a musicians ego and/or subconcious. I've heard more than a few musicians, begginners and advanced, speak of "non-standard" tunings as if those who used them were "out of the mainstream" and, as such, were either cheating, or vocally weak. This is easily demonstrated as sheer non-sense when taking a look at the plethora of famous singer/songwriter/guitarists who use, or did use them, routinely.

2) When it's really desirable to capo up to standard, having the capo on the first fret makes playing chords up the neck confusing, because it reconfigures fret markers. Super good players can account for that I suppose, but when I capo up from a half step down, I prefer to capo up to the second fret when possible to avoid these "odd" positionings. If all chords of a song are near the capo (i.e. predominately open as opposed to bar chords), this is not an issue.

3) Does tuning a guitar a half or full step down change how a guitar matures over time? I don't know. It would be interesting to ask the worlds greatest luthiers whether the physics of any particular guitar design pre-supposes that the guitar will be played in standard over most its life.

Answer (score 1):

Well, aside from the fact that they just like it I will admit that there are some songs which sound strikingly different in tone and mood just from a simple 1/2 step down-tuning.

But ultimately, it is my belief that guitarists tune a 1/2 step down in order to make it easier for a piano/keyboardist to play along. Many times when guitarists are working with others in a band or just doing their own songwriting, in regular tuning playing along with a guitarist using a piano/keyboard, one has to be fairly familiar with the piano's scales and chords to play something that sounds good. Meaning, you'd have to be a rather accomplished pianist in order to "freestyle" along with a guitarist.
If you didn't know, there's a dirty secret about playing the piano- if you limit yourself to playing on (pretty much) only the black keys, anything you play will pretty much sound good, or at least correct. When a guitarist tunes down 1/2 step, it is suddenly tuned such that it has essentially made the black keys the white keys for the piano player. 
So, it is my assertion that 1/2 step down is mostly because it makes it incredibly easy to play along with on the piano. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's because to make the pitch of the guitar tune agrees with the vocal's pitch :) If one doesn't tune properly , the pitch would sound different . For example playing a 'C' note , and suddenly a 'C#' pitch will be heard . If the vocal sings a C , guitar must play a 'C' too .

Comment: On the assumption the vocalist has perfect pitch and is a pedant, this could be true.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I play in dropped A tuning. Why?

The informal reason: The metal band Suicide Silence is the reason I wanted to start playing guitar in the first place and I could not play their songs unless I was in the same tuning as them.

This opened up a WHOLE WORLD for me!

Remember, no matter what tuning you're in, **you can always go higher, not lower**. Meaning, in dropped A, **I can play songs that are in ANY tuning**, except for like dropped F which is sooo rare.

Any song I learn, I instantly transcribe to dropped A. I really don't see the need for me to play in any other tuning, to be honest. I play bass guitar, and higher tunings just don't have the "oomph" I need.

Look at it this way: When you down tune a guitar, you are loosening the strings. Which means the strings actually vibrate more when you play and if you pair that with distortion UGH it's amazing. The crunch is unbeatable.

Down tuning was actually founded by jazz and blues musicians. The looser strings are the trick to their play style.

And when you play say, songs that are played in standard but in dropped A, you bring your vibrato and your crunch from the lower tuning with you and create a style that is your own.

I tune my guitar like this: **A/E/A/D**.

So, I have a lower A and a higher A. This allows me to create melodies with the two strings that I cannot do in other tunings.

Also! The band Motograter (the band Ivan Moody was in before Five Finger Death Punch) has a horizontal bass guitar that they built that only has two strings both tuned in A. So I know when I play that band, I only need to use the 2 strings and it sounds identical! And the melodies are so awesome you would never know they only use 2 strings.