# How to find the right tuning for arranging songs?

Tags: theory, guitar, tuning, alternative-tunings

I want to know how to find the right tuning to be comfortable and able to combine many different voicings on a single guitar, I also wanted to spice up my arrangement. I saw kent nishimura on YouTube, he always changes his tuning and he rarely uses standard tuning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Choose the Best Alternate Tuning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/88063/how-to-choose-the-best-alternate-tuning)

Comment: I get the impression that this question is asking for a tuning to optimally cover the general skill of arranging, rather than how to pick a tuning for specific songs. If that's true, this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Every tuning gives different possibilities for use of open strings, barree chords and other patterns. It's matter of your creativity, techniques you use, preferences and style how you can use it. I'm not sure if this question can have a definite answer.

Comment: I think standard tuning makes the most different voicings available. If there was a more comprehensive one to be found, wouldn't that then become the most used - and eventually, the new standard? Changing tunings, or having several guitars is obviously an option, but not what I glean from the question.

Comment: @user45266 - I get the sense that the question *is* asking for specific-song tuning given its mention that Kent Nishimura "always changes his tuning".

Comment: @Tim debatable. Standard tuning is many centuries old. Today there is enormous amount of repertoire written for standard tuning, so it cannot be simply abandoned. I don't see any obvious reason for it to be superior to e.g. lute tuning, with major third between 3rd and 4th string, instead of 2nd and 3rd. Unless you know the specific reason why one convention won over the other, I'd suspect it was matter of tradition.

Comment: example, the key of a song is in Amaj then i need to tune my guitar that can play all chords in Amaj with mood sound open string.