Looking for an alternative guitar tuning to fit classical counterpoint exercises
Have a very strange problem, hopefully there is a lurking genius who can solve it cause I'm stumped.
I'm studying a stuffy counterpoint composition manual written hundreds of years ago and trying to adapt it for guitar. Obviously the manual was written for keys, and thus the problem. These lessons require that I'm able to play root position, first and second inversions of major and minor triads, and also third inversions of dominant seventh chords; all as moveable shapes.
Unfortunately with standard EBGDAE tuning, it is basically impossible to play most root position dominant seventh chords as moveable shapes, or the other inversions for that matter. Playing the minor/major root, first and second inversions is also a bit uncomfortable though it is possible.
Does anyone know of a tuning that makes it possible to play these chords with moveable shapes?
The only alternative I came up with is DAFCAE which does allow me to play the traditional inversions of minor, major and dominant chords. But I'm sure someone has a better idea than this.

Related question that's for the general case: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/88063/how-to-choose-the-best-alternate-tuning

Are you talking about playing these chords and inversions as closed voicings, for example: 1357, 357R, 57R3, 7R35? Pretty much any chord and inversion is playable with open voicings in standard tuning. I also assume you mean playing the notes simultaneously and not as arpeggios.

Playing triads, all of major and minor chords in root, 1st and 2nd inversions are readily playable using standard tuning. After all, a triad will only need to contain three notes.
Dominant chords will only need four notes to qualify, and with six strings to choose from, there shouldn't be a problem there either, not even in 3rd inversion. You may need to play finger style - all notes may not be on adjacent strings - but all is doable. So, I'd tend to stick to standard tuning for all - after all, that tuning has become standard for a good reason - it covers the vast majority of chords used by guitarists, namely major, minor, dominant sevenths, even major/minor sevenths are easily played, as movable, transferrable, barre shapes.
Being able to look at the said piece may change this answer considerably, but in essence, it stands.

Do you know of any chord diagrams for dominant sevenths in root position, first second and third inversions?

Yes. As long as the lowest note is root, for root position, 3rd for 1st inversion, 5th for 2nd inversion, and b7 for 3rd inversion, and there are the three  other notes, in any order, on any higher strings, they will constitute those inversions.

I recommend working them out! A chord diagram will shortcut of course but working out each of the inversions will really help your fretboard knowledge and understanding of how the intervals stack for various inversions. As Tim says you can grab all the notes in any order above the bass note for various inversions, but the drop 2 voicings (of which the standard barre chord shape is one, root position) are almost all reachable, with just few fringe chords that are not practical to play. Its a good exercise to do!
